# How do I clear a DataTable if there is no data to process?

Tags: jquery, python, datatables

I have a form which has a dataTable in it.

I have the following in my jQuery script:

```
      $.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
          table = $('#search_table').dataTable( {
              destroy: true,
              "data": data,
              "columns": [ 
                  {"title": "Title"},
                  {"title": "Rank"},
                  {"title": "Planning"},
                  {"title": "Action"}
              ] 
          });
          $('#table_div').prop("hidden", false);
      });
```

However, when the get_JSON does not get data (it returns null), the table shows the data that was previously present. my $('#folders') is a dropdown, and when the Search button is clicked, this function is called. My backend is python (flask), and it returns the following for good data:

```
[
    ["test worklog", 44, 3, "Update"],
    ["some title for issue in folder 5", 32, 42, "Update"]
]
```

when it hits a folder that is empty, the value returned is null. How can I clear the DataTable in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in my server code. If I did not find any folders, I was returning None (null in js). Now, I return an empty list, and it shows an empty table as expected.